Why at the end of this video a tiny drop of water goes upwards?
A guy recorded a drop of water at 20,000 fps with ultra slowmo here with macro lens:
https://www.reddit.com/r/nextfuckinglevel/s/ERxrzjAgEe
As you can see, at the end of the video the droplet goes upwards. Why? How does physics explain it?

Related: Galilean cannon.

Stacked Ball Drop video from Physics Girl.

The drops bounce on the surface. Some of the upward motion comes from bouncing.
There is a succession of smaller and smaller drops. It looks like the last smallest drop floats away. I can think of two things that might account for this.
It might have blown away. Wind exerts a force on the surface. So the force is proportional to the area. A force will produce a bigger acceleration on an object with a smaller mass. Mass is proportional to the volume. So how do surface area and volume change when a drop gets small?
$$a = F/m \propto A/V$$
$$= \frac{4\pi r^2}{4/3\pi r^3}$$
$$= 1/3r$$
A smaller drop is accelerated more readily by wind. So even a small current might have blown the smallest drop away.
Static electricity might have attracted the drop. Matter is usually neutral, or pretty close to it. You can make charges accumulate on a cat by rubbing its fur. But even without rubbing, and object might have a few extra or missing electrons. If this happens to a drop, it will be attracted or repelled by other nearby objects that have some charge.
It is hard to say how much charge an object will wind up with. But you might guess that if a few electrons are floating around, the number a drop will hit will be proportional to the surface area. And again the acceleration will be proportional to the volume. If these guesses are right, a small drop will be more affected by static electricity.

That's because of Surface Tension, the properties of liquid inside the container and on the surface of the container vary a lot as the particles of liquid inside the container are attracted by all the particles of liquid in all direction but at surface, there is atmosphere whose particles cannot exerted as much force as the particles of liquid below the surface of liquid on the topmost surface of liquid due to which it behaves like a stretched membrane which tries to minimize the volume/area. That's why you can see those droplets in spherical shape to minimize it's volume as there are pulled by the central particles of drop.
This membrane acts like a trampoline providing force due to surface tension. See link at 8:15. But when this drop of water comes in contact with the surface at a slow speed, the particles of container pull away large part of this drop as the topmost part of the drop is again engulf by the surface layer of the drop causing recursion.
